# Websphere MQ connection pooling

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, connection-pooling, apache-commons-pool

Is there any connection pool library for Websphere MQ in Java? I tried to implement connection pool for WebSphere MQ using Apache Commons Pool, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms. It was forked from the mature ActiveMQ JMS Pool and enhanced to provide JMS 2.0 functionality. It is generic (i.e. no ties to ActiveMQ) so it will work with any JMS implementation.

Comment: Did you take a look at the link I posted in my answer?  It has the relevant documentation along with an example demonstrating how to use the pool.  As far as the API goes, it's essentially just the JMS API.  Please refer to the link I provided for additional details.

Comment: How we can achieve connection polling without adding this dependency

Comment: Rather than comment on this question (which has already been answered) you need to ask a new one, @NilayTiwari.

Comment: @NilayTiwari, I saw the [other question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571304/jms-connection-pooling-with-ibm-mq-client) which is basically just a duplicate of this one. You didn't say that you didn't want to add this (or any) dependency. If you want a connection pool you will either have to add a dependency or implement your own pool.