# JMS connection pooling with IBM MQ Client

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We are using MQIPT 9.2 between our IBM MQ 9.x server and IBM MQ clients. We're also using the IBM MQ client jar in Java to connect to the queue manager to push and receive messages which is working fine. However connection creation is taking time and every time it will take time if we create connection just in time.

How we can implement JMS connection pooling for IBM MQ?

The following depicts our connectivity:

[[image]][1

Is there any standard way so that we can implement connection pooling?

Used Code below

```java
System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<Starting test for push messages>>>>>>>>>>");

try {

    // Create a keystore object for the truststore
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    char[] keyPassphrase = "*******".toCharArray();
    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(
            "JKS File path"),
            keyPassphrase);
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    System.out.println("SSL certificates loaded in message sending");
    // Create default MQ connection factory
    MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    factory.setQueueManager(QMGRNAME);
    factory.setHostName(HOSTNAME);
    factory.setChannel(CHANNEL);
    factory.setPort(1414);
    factory.setSSLFipsRequired(false);
    factory.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    factory.setClientReconnectTimeout(100);
    factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, user);
    factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
    factory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);

    factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "cipher suite");


    mqConnection = (MQQueueConnection) factory.createQueueConnection();
    
    
    MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) mqConnection.createQueueSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    // Start the connection
    System.out.println("Connection starting while sending message");
    mqConnection.start();
    System.out.println("Connection started while sending message");
    for (int i = 0; i <50; i++) {
        System.out.println("Preparing message before sending");
        long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session
                .createTextMessage("SimplePTP - msg" + uniqueNumber);
        System.out.println("message prepared while sending , text: " + message.getText());
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(destinationName);
        MQMessageProducer producer = (MQMessageProducer) session.createProducer(destination);

        // And, send the message
        producer.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message****************:\n" + message);
    }

    /*
     * if (connection != null) { System.out.
     * println("*************connection closing after message sent********************"
     * ); connection.close(); System.out.
     * println("*************connection closed after message sent********************"
     * ); }
     */
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<Test ended>>>>>>>>>>>>");
} catch (JMSException j) {
    j.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    System.out.println("finally block after message sent************ ");
    if (mqConnection != null) {
        try {
            mqConnection.close();
            System.out.println("connection closed after message sent in finally block\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<Test ended from finally >>>>>>>>>>>>");
}
```

When using the above code connection creation takes time and it's creating and closing a connection *for each messsage*. This is a bad practice so I created a list and added connection into it which works well. However, I want to use a proper connection pool instead.

Comment: Do you run your jns application stand alone or in a J2EE app server?

Comment: Can you show your JMS related code in the MQ client?

Comment: added code in  question. We also used this with Camel JMS route but camel is creating new connection for each message

Comment: Spring has a caching connection factory, is this something that you can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
       id="source.pooledConnectionFactory" primary="true">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="1"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="0"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="factory"/>
</bean>
```

(sorry for the XML when you posted Java DSL, but you get the idea).  Basically, wrap your connection factory with the ActiveMQ JMS pooled connection factory.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.messaginghub</groupId>
        <artifactId>pooled-jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    JmsPoolConnectionFactory pooledCF = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();
    
    pooledCF.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    pooledCF.setMaxConnections(1);
```

The `org.messaginghub` project is a branch of the ActiveMQ code and has no ActiveMQ dependencies.

Comment: Doug, he is using IBM MQ not ActiveMQ.  Does the ActiveMQ JMS pooled connection factory work with an IBM MQ connection factory?

Comment: Yes. Note that the is the 'org.apache.activemq.jms' (jms) variant.  It is designed to wrap any JMS connection factory.  There is another variant that is designed specifically for the ActiveMQ connection factory.   The `messaginghub` fork is nearly identical, with the removal of the connection timeout.

Comment: [github](https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS/blob/testing/bridge/src/main/java/com/redhat/gss/bridge/configurator/MqConfigurationProducer.java) for those that are interested.

Comment: how i can set max connection limit with pool jms

Comment: as above, with the `setMaxConnections()` function.  Note, however, that the Spring JMS code will create a single connection, and then start multiple JMS sessions on that connection.